# How to use Content Publishing API for Instagram not being Instagram Partner?

Tags: api, instagram, publishing

We are trying to develop an application for scheduling social media posts. 
So far we have the Facebook intergration ready, and we are heading to implement Instagram,
but according to the official documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing) -> "The Content Publishing API is in closed beta with Facebook Marketing Partners and Instagram Partners only. We are not accepting new applicants at this time.". 
Can you please tell us how we can do a content publishing to Instagram using their API for better scheduling and/or automation? 
Is the Instagram Partners program closed for good? Can we apply for acceptance?
Is there any other way to publish to instagram a bulk of posts (say 30-40) to different accounts if not using the API?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone? I've read this [article](https://influencermarketinghub.com/how-to-cross-post-to-instagram-from-a-facebook-page/) about cross-posting to Instagram and it looks like an option for us, but I cannot duplicate all the steps listed in it - namely having the Instagram as option when posting to Facebook (last step). 

Any help with this matter will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hello? Anyone with Instagram experience?

Comment: +1 Looking for access to the content publishing API too. Have yet to find anything revealing how to get around the closed beta. 

Comment: you can use private api like mgp25

Comment: From some days the url in the OP doesn't exist anymore..

Comment: What happend to this API?

Comment: Any news with the API edge?
Is it open now or still in closed beta phase?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This link which is right here might help you publish contents on Instagram, especially, Photos. (Link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced)
On the left, check for 'photos upload', there you'll find some methods to publish contents.
They've showed it with an example using cURL.</strike>

[*Edit:*] **As @[rodin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1095814/rodins) notified, you can now post contents(using Instagram Content publishing API)  to instagram without being a facebook partner.

For more info, visit [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/).**

Comment: Hi Pavana. I saw that, but it doesn't say it covers the Instagram platform. So you're saying that if I use the object-id of the instagram business profile I can post images to it?

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you're trying to implement scheduling posts to post on instagram using your own created app, either for Android or iOS devices, or even webapps, you've got an option for that. However, if you're trying to schedule to post via scripts like pytohn, then there's no way as of now. Also, business profile is just an advantage over normal profile. Yes, you need a business account if you want to post pictures. Checkout GRAPH API EXPLORER, you'll get an option in the right to add permissions that you need for instagram. - INSTAGRAM GRAPH API is what you need basically.

Comment: Now you can use instagram content publishing API without being a Facebook partner: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

Comment: Thank you for letting me know:) I just updated the answer above as well <3